# Cloud SQL import Data from bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

1. if i want to import data from storage, command ask Do you want to continue (Y/n)?. Is there a way to import by php without this question?

   gcloud sql import sql sqlinstance gs://bucket/****.sql.gz --database=****

what was wrong here?

2. can i make more than one import on same time?
3. Load data infile did not work, can i use load data local infile from the VM (Compute Engine)?

sorry iam new, and thanks for your help

Comment: For the number 3 you will need to edit your question. How it didin't work? what error / issue are you encountering? share with us what did actually happened and what is the expected result not things that didin't happened

Comment: thanks for your reply. the error is, that another import is runnig

Answer (score 0):

1. To run a gcloud command in headless mode (without the Y/n question) use the [--quiet](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--quiet) flag
2. There is no wildcard option using 4 stars (****) I recommend you to take a look to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/WildcardNames) to use the wildcards.
3. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/importing) are listed the possible methods to import data into Cloud SQL and importing directly from Compute Engine is not listed, you will need to export to Cloud Storage before moving importing into Cloud SQL

Comment: 1. thanks i found it.
2. is fixed, too
3. yes, this is fixed.

the only problem is, to make parallel imports.

since today i get this error:

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in /projects/cron-offers/xxxxx/xxxx.php:243
 Stack trace:

Comment: Ok, as stated in the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export) "You can perform only one import or export operation at a time for each instance". Try to import files one by one ;-)